# How to check if data is already present in database using entity framework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

Say I have a database with two tables, boats and sailors. Say I also have a lot of text files containing information with sailors who have serviced on boats.
Naturally I do not want to have two different rows in sailors being the same sailor. Does that mean that when I go through the text file, do I have to check with the database every time I see a sailor whether or not that sailor is already in the database?
Is there not some elequent way of checking if the sailor in question is already in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a `DbContext db` with a `DbSet<Sailor> Sailors`, if you don't want to check with the database every time you can create a list of all the IDs:

```
var ids = db.Sailors.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

And check everything against that object:

```
var exists = ids.Contains(idFromFile);
```

Comment: If he wants to use LINQ, than he can also use .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == idFromFile);

Comment: I was kinda hoping it wouldn't be necessary, but I guess it will have to be this way.
On a side note, is it considered bad form to have several for-loops inside an using (dbcontext db)?

Comment: @user1815201 It depends. But it most likely is bad, in the sense that EF sets are better manipulated using LINQ To Entities, not even `foreach` (let alone `for`). This is because the LINQ-made queries will be constructed and evaluated as late as possible, which means they will be more optimized than manual fetching inside the loops. (Of course, I should point out that in my example with `ToList()` you lose that benefit for that particular operator, because you fully enumerate the enumerable.)

Comment: Oh, what I actually meant/thought about doing is looping over a lot of data and using the dbcontext to see what of my data already exists in the database.

Answer (score 0):

this one is correct way of optimally check data existence.

```
var exists = db.Sailors.Any(x => x.Id == idFromFile);
```